# Преобразование const char [] в String

Tags: c++, строки, ооп

Допустим, есть такой код:

```
class String
{
    private:
        enum {SZ = 80};
        char str[SZ];
    public:
        String()
        { strcpy(str, ""); }
        String(char s[])
        { strcpy(str, s); }
        void display() const
        { cout << str; }
        void operator+=(String ss)
        {
            if (strlen(str) + strlen(ss.str) < SZ)
                strcat(str, ss.str);
            else
                cout << "Overflow!" << endl; exit(1);
        }
};

int main()
{
    String s1("str1 ");
    String s2("str2");
}
```

На 2 операции в main компилятор жалуется, мол, нельзя преобразовать const char[10] в String. Но почему, если есть соответствующий для этого конструктор?

Comment: Попробуйте `String(const char s[])`...

Comment: спасибо, помогло, но вылезла следующая ошибка: 
Ошибка C4996 'strcat': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcat_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: Это не ошибка, а предупреждение. Используйте? как вам предлагают, `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`... Или безопасные (с `_s`) функции для работы со строками.

Comment: Еще бы хорошо использовать `strncpy` вместо `strcpy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет такого конструктора. Есть конструктор для `char*`, а не для `const char*`.
Замените

```
String(char s[])
```

на

```
String(const char s[])
```

C++ запрещает присваивание указателя на `const` указателю на не `const`. Если бы такое было разрешено, то можно было бы менять константные обьекты.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что вы *обещаете* изменять в конструкторе передаваемую строку. А изменять литерал нельзя...

```
String(const char * s)
```

вас спасет. Понимаете, `const` в C++ применяют не только, и не столько потому, что это загадочно звучит и красиво смотрится... :)

Comment: конечно понимаю, но в книге, которую я изучаю работа с указателями будет только в 10 главе, так что расчёт идет на то, что я не знаю, что это за волшебная звёздочка такая :)  Я почти дословно переписал код автора, адаптировав под задачу, но в его коде конструктор пишется так же - String(char s[]). Так что в следующий раз буду думать, слушать автора или не слушать, спасибо вам

Comment: @АлександрII Без const работало до С++11, может у вас просто книга старая.